# Xcode, iOS: Same RGB color gives different colors

Tags: xcode, ios13

When I apply same color components (R, G and B) as shown in the picture, they produce different colors. How can I fix this issue?

The left is more darker than the right one.

[image]

Comment: You don't think about it. It will work correctly on real device.

Comment: No, it's not! When I apply UIColor() in code, it does look same. But not from Storyboard.